# xkeyval Error: `HEIGHT' ('WIDTH') undefined in families `psvectorian'

Tags: memoir, glossaries, xkeyval, psvectorian

I'd like to change the title of my glossary, say, List of Symbols, as follows (using some entities borrowed from the `psvectorian` package).

```
\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\[\baselineskip]List of Symbols\\[0.9\baselineskip]\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\
```

Here is my `MWE`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}

\newcommand{\abc}[1]{\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\[\baselineskip]#1\\[0.9\baselineskip]\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\}

\loadglsentries{gloss-symb}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2.5cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
}

\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    
    \clearpage
    
    \renewcommand{\glossaryname}{\abc{List of Symbols}}
    
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
        \printnoidxglossary[style=mylong]

    \newpage
    
    \gls{sigma} is an event set.
\end{document}
```

in which `gloss-symb.tex` just includes

```
\newglossaryentry{sigma}{name={\ensuremath{\Sigma}}, description={Event set}}
```

However, I've faced the following errors:

```
Package xkeyval Error: `HEIGHT' undefined in families `psvectorian'. \end{document}

Package xkeyval Error: `WIDTH' undefined in families `psvectorian'. \end{document}
```

The `psvectorian` [manual](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian/psvectorian.pdf) (the page 2) already noted that `width` and `height` are indeed valid keys. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`width` and `height` do in fact exist, but `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` do not.  The problem is that at some point when typesetting `\glossaryname` the macro is expanded and `\MakeUppercase`d, so `width` becomes `WIDTH` and you get the error.  This is the problem of intermixing code (`\psvectorian` and such) with text:  some code that expects pure text will not behave well with general commands.

One easy way out is to pack the `\psvectorian` commands into `\protected` macros so that they don't expand before uppercasing (thus they aren't uppercased either).  Dividing your definition of `\abc` into three parts gets the job done:

```latex
\protected\def\abcbefore{\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\[\baselineskip]}
\protected\def\abcafter{\\[0.9\baselineskip]\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\}
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{\abcbefore#1\abcafter}
```

---

Compilable code:

```latex
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{filecontents*}{gloss-symb}
\newglossaryentry{sigma}{name={\ensuremath{\Sigma}}, description={Event set}}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}

\protected\def\abcbefore{\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\[\baselineskip]}
\protected\def\abcafter{\\[0.9\baselineskip]\hfil\hspace*{-3.5cm}\psvectorian[height=3mm, width=8cm]{88}\hfil\\}
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{\abcbefore#1\abcafter}

\loadglsentries{gloss-symb}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2.5cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
        {\end{longtable}}%
}

\makenoidxglossaries

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{\abc{List of Symbols}}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\printnoidxglossary[style=mylong]

\newpage

\gls{sigma} is an event set.
\end{document}
```